# How to convert postgis to OSM?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, postgis, osmosis

I'm using Osmosis to export the Postgis tables to .osm file.

I'm using the following command to generate the .osm file.

```
osmosis --read-pgsql host="localhost" database="pgsnapshot" user="postgres" password="postgres" --dataset-dump --write-xml file='output.osm"
```

It yields an empty osm file. The database which I'm using contains the following tables with no empty columns.

- action
- nodes_tags
- nodes
- relation_members
- relations
- relations_tag
- way_tag
- schema_info
- users
- way_nodes
- ways

I've searched for the solution but mostly I'm getting search results on osm2pgsql. I want the opposite of the same.

Comment: What happens when you query your database with this for example:
SELECT * FROM nodes LIMIT 1;

Comment: All the tables(nodes, relations, users, ways, nodes_tags, relations_tag, way_tag) which are generated by executing the .sql files through osmosis have no record.

Comment: Do you mean that your tables are empty? In that case it could explain why osmosis cannot extract an osm file from it!